# Does <do-status> with level "retry" block any other event from being processed?

Tags: novell, novell-idm, netiq

I have a NetIQ (Novell) IDM 4.0.1 driver. In a policy I have a `<do-status>` rule with level `retry`.

Does this `retry` block any other event from being processed?

From the logic of the application the event for (A) can not be processed until the object (B) is associated by the very same driver. Therefore I have added the `retry` rule on (A). However, it seems that the event for (B) is blocked when the event for (A) is waiting for being retried. If I use `veto` instead of `retry` for (A) then the event for (B) is processed regulary.

Is the behaviour specified somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This takes the top event in the queue, and retries it every 'interval'  (which is defined in an Engine Control Value, defaults to 30 seconds).

So yes, it blocks all following events until it completes and stops being a retry.

What you could do is much simpler.  In the Input Transform policy set, look for the operation add-association since that is when the object is successfully added to the connected system.

Then do your rule B stuff.

Unless you mean two different objects A and B, that are otherwise unrelated.  If so, would let object A logic go through, and when you see object B come through then do the work on object A that is needed.

Comment: I look for add-association in the input transformation policy. How can I start a synchronisation on B when add-association happens? This is the "rule B stuff" which is to be done.